# Spring Data JPA getting a Projection from an Entity with a Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

In my application I have a Hero Entity. I also want to be able to return a list of each hero id and name. I got it working with this:

```
@Repository
public interface HeroEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<HeroEntity, Long> {
@Query("select s.id, s.name from HEROES s")
List<Object> getIdAndName();
}

// in controller:
@GetMapping
public List<Object> getHeroNames() {
    return heroEntityRepository.getIdAndName();
}
```

I tried the suggestion in another post to substitute the Object with a Interface, but then I receive a list of null values ( [{"name":null,"id":null},{"name":null,"id":null}, // etc ).
The custom Interface:

```
public interface HeroNameAndId {

    Long getId();
    String getName();
}
```

When making a Entity with only id and name values I received a 'ConverterNotFoundException'. Im not sure what the right way to go is. I have it working with Object but this doesn't seem very clean.

My HeroEntity:

```
@Getter
@Builder
@Entity(name = "HEROES")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HeroEntity extends HasId<Long> {

    private String name;
    private String shortName;
    private String attributeId;

    @ElementCollection private List<String> translations;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) private HeroIconEntity icon;

    private String role;
    private String type;
    private String releaseDate;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) private List<AbilityEntity> abilities;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) private List<TalentEntity> talents;
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class HasId<T> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter
    @Getter
    private T id;
}
```

Comment: after you introduced Interface(it is called Projection). Did you change your Repository method in any way? if so waht did u change?

Comment: No, I only substituted the Object for HeroNameAndId Interface in the methods (eg. List<HeroNameAndId> getHeroNames() ).

Comment: you have to change your repository method from `List<Object> getIdAndName();` to `Collection<HeroNameAndId> getIdAndName();`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You must use field aliases to make @Query with projection work:

```
@Query("select s.id as id, s.name as name from HEROES s")
```

The aliases must match the names in your HeroNameAndId interface.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: I still not get the interface but an object with the specified values. Any idea?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli do you know why that is? I had a query with projection and without aliases working fine in Boot 1. I've upgraded and that broke for me and forced me to add the aliases. I haven't found anything in changelog of Spring Data JPA.

Comment: I'm sorry but no.

Comment: hi Simon can you tell us, is @query will support DB independence

Comment: If you are executing JPQL then it's independant but if you execute SQL then it's not

Comment: Thanks ,Iin my case value, if id field is getting null, answer solved issue Thank you!

Comment: Strange; @maciej, my code base also had a working projection query that didn't use aliases in Spring 4/Hibernate 4 which broke after an upgrade to Spring 5/Hibernate 5. This did the trick though; thanks @simon-martinelli; +1 coming your way!